# Error when run clickhouse docker image on mac os

Tags: macos, docker, installation, yandex, clickhouse

I had exception when I installed yandex clickhouse from docker image.

`docker run -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server 
   yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server`

`docker logs 54aa87e92a2c 
Include not found: clickhouse_remote_servers
Include not found: clickhouse_compression
POCO ERROR: Exception: Could not determine local time zone: boost::filesystem::canonical: No such file or directory: "/usr/share/zoneinfo/"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::Exception'
  what():  Exception`

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've fixed the problem in the latest images. Please execute:

```
docker pull yandex/clickhouse-client
docker pull yandex/clickhouse-server
```

The source of the problem lies in the Ubuntu base image used for building ClickHouse images: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/2863.

Comment: Thanks, it was really fast fix:)